# How to solve Unknown package x3270.sh exit code 127 error when updating Cygwin

Tags: unix, cygwin, software-update

I got this error when I updated Cygwin.

[image]

As a new Cygwin user I don't understand much. Is this a critical error? Is there any crucial problem if I can't fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of this message remove the `/etc/postinstall/x3270.sh` file. If you want to clear everything, install the x3270 package, then remove the x3270 and suite3270 packages. <sup>[source](http://shelleyness.com/questions/29149/pacote-de-software-nao-descarregavel)</sup>